# ¿Por qué no funciona Ajax?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, json

Estoy intentando hacer que entre funcione esta página, todo parece estar bien el `php`, el `html` también, sin embargo no se comunican los datos `json` entre el `php` y el `jquery`, he intentado comprobar con `alerts` hasta donde funciona, y parece ser que no funciona a partir de la función done.

The `HTML` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Registro Chat</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Chat 2.0</h1>
<div class="container col-md- mt-4">
    <form id="formulario">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usuario">Nombre de Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Introduzca el nombre de usuario">
        <p id="p-usuario"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Introduzca su email">
        <p id="p-email"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contra1">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="contra1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Introduzca una contraseña">
        <p id="p-contra1"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contra2">Repita la Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="contra2" placeholder="Repita su contraseña">
        <p id="p-contra2"></p>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success bg-success">Enviar</button>
      <a href="principal.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success bg-success">Inicio de Sesión</button></a>
    </form>
</div>  
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="accionregistro.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `JQuery` file:

```
$(document).ready(principal);

function principal(){

$('#formulario').submit(runAjax);
}

function runAjax(event){

var enviados = {
    'usuario' : $('#usuario').val(),
    'email' : $('#email').val(),
    'contra1' : $('#contra1').val(),
    'contra2' : $('#contra2').val()
    };

$.ajax({
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : 'backendregistro.php',
    data        : enviados,
    dataType    : 'json',
    encode      : true  
})
.done(function(datos){
    alert();

    if(datos.exito){
            alert();
            $('0#p-usuario').text(datos.mensaje);
    }else{
        if(datos.error.vacio){
                alert(datos.error.vacio);
                //$('#p-usuario').text(datos.error.vacio);
        }
        if(datos.error.usuario){
                $('#p-usuario').text(datos.error.usuario);
        }
        if(datos.error.email){
                $('#p-email').text(datos.error.email);
        }
        if(datos.error.notmatch){
                $('#p-contraseña1').text(datos.error.notmatch);
        }
        }

});
event.preventDefault();
}
```

`PHP` file:

```
  <?php  
 $error=array();
 $datos=array();

         if(empty($_POST['usuario'])||empty($_POST['contra1'])||empty($_POST['contra2'])||empty($_POST['email'])){
$error['vacio']="No puede haber campos en blanco";
  }else{
  echo
  $usuario = $_POST['usuario'].
  $email = $_POST['email'].
  $contraseña1 = $_POST['contra1'].
  $contraseña2 = $_POST['contra2'];
  }
  //definimos la conexion a la base de datos
  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','chat','chat2019','chat');

  //comprobamos si el email ya existe
  $mysqli -> query("select * from users where email='".$email."'");
  if($mysqli->affected_rows!=0&&!empty($email)){
  $error['email']="Ese email ya está registrado";
  } 
  //comprobamos que no exista el usuario
  $mysqli->query("select * from users where user='".$usuario."'");
  if($mysqli->affected_rows!=0 && !empty($usuario)){
  $error['usuario']="Ya existe ese nombre de usuario";
  }

  //si no hay errores hacemos el insert
  if(empty($error)){
  $datos['exito']=true;
  $datos['mensaje']="Usuario registrado correctamente";
  $mysqli->query("insert into users values ('".$usuario."','".$contraseña1."','".$email."')");
  }else{
  $datos['exito']=false;
  $datos['error']=$error;
  }
```

Cuando compruebo con la consola del navegador si todo esta bien parece que sí, el `json` parece que se envía pero no funciona la función `.done()`. Soy muy noob en programación web y que seguramente sea insegura la forma en que estoy haciendo esto pero solo quiero saber porque no funciona. Gracias.

Comment: Hi, this is the Spanish version of StackOverflow. Please translate your answer o use the English version of the site.

Comment: Por si existe la remota posibilidad de que no sepa ingles y solo haya usado el traductor para traducir la pregunta, traduzco el comentario anterior:                               

Hola, esta es la versión española de StackOverflow. Por favor, traduce tu respuesta o usa la versión inglesa del sitio.

Comment: Perdón, pensé que estaba publicando en el inglés, ya he editado la pregunta y la he puesto en castellano. Siento las molestias.

Comment: En $('0#p-usuario') ese zero está de más.

Comment: si, el 0 ha sido un error al escribir la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El error es porque en el ajax, colocaste el atributo dataType: 'json', esto fuerza a que tu script retorne un objeto de tipo json. Si no retorna un objeto de tipo json, tu formulario quedará en un estado error que lo podrás observar en la consola.

Para poder retornar un json en php utiliza:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("ok"=>"Guardado con éxito"));
```

Comment: he probrado pero no ha solucionado el problema

Answer (score 0):

he resuelto el problema, era de PHP, el error era que faltaban espacios en la funcion affected_rows. Una vez aplicados espacios antes y despues ya funciona. Gracias por las respuesas.